# How to correctly create OpenGL texture from Image?

Tags: objective-c, image, macos, opengl, textures

Can anyone give me information about how to correctly create OpenGL texture from image (NSImage or image file) while using ARC? I tried using CGImage (something like CGImageSource->CGImage->GLubyte...), but that caused pretty big memory leak.

Sample code:

```
    _bottom_source = CGImageSourceCreateWithData((__bridge CFDataRef)[_bottom_layer_image TIFFRepresentation], NULL);
    _bottom_cgimage =  CGImageSourceCreateImageAtIndex(_bottom_source, 0, NULL);
    _cg_bottom_image_width = CGImageGetWidth(_bottom_cgimage);
    _cg_bottom_image_height = CGImageGetHeight(_bottom_cgimage);
    _bottom_image_data = (GLubyte *) calloc(_cg_bottom_image_width * _cg_bottom_image_height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    _bottom_context = CGBitmapContextCreate(_bottom_image_data, _cg_bottom_image_width, _cg_bottom_image_height, 8, _cg_bottom_image_width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(_bottom_cgimage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(_bottom_context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)_cg_bottom_image_width, (CGFloat)_cg_bottom_image_height), _bottom_cgimage);
    CGContextRelease(_bottom_context);

    CIImage *_gray_out_ciimage = [[CIImage alloc] initWithCGImage:_bottom_cgimage];
    CIFilter *gray_out_filter = [CIFilter filterWithName:@"CIColorControls"];
    [gray_out_filter setDefaults];
    [gray_out_filter setValue:_gray_out_ciimage forKey:@"inputImage"];
    [gray_out_filter setValue:0 forKey:@"inputSaturation"];
    _gray_out_ciimage = [gray_out_filter valueForKey:@"outputImage"];
    NSBitmapImageRep *_temporaryRep = [[NSBitmapImageRep alloc] initWithCIImage:_gray_out_ciimage];

    _top_cgimage = _temporaryRep.CGImage;
    _cg_top_image_width = CGImageGetWidth(_top_cgimage);
    _cg_top_image_height = CGImageGetHeight(_top_cgimage);
    _top_image_data = (GLubyte *) calloc(_cg_top_image_width * _cg_top_image_height * 4, sizeof(GLubyte));
    _top_context = CGBitmapContextCreate(_top_image_data, _cg_top_image_width, _cg_top_image_height, 8, _cg_top_image_width * 4, CGImageGetColorSpace(_top_cgimage), kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);
    CGContextDrawImage(_top_context, CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, (CGFloat)_cg_top_image_width, (CGFloat)_cg_top_image_height), _top_cgimage);
    CGContextRelease(_top_context);
//wielding *_image_data as OpenGL textures images and after that:
    CGImageRelease(_bottom_cg_image);
    CGImageRelease(_top_cg_image);
    free(_bottom_image_data);
    free(_top_image_data);
```

---

```
it acts like that:
That code, that I have written in question now works like that:

1. I launch app. In activity monitor `Real Mem:78MB` and `Virtual Mem: 120MB`.
2. I load 389kb image. In activity monitor now `Real Mem:181.3MB` and `Virtual Mem:161.1MB`.
3. Then I load 5.3MB image. And now in activity monitor `Real Mem: 519MB` and `Virtual Mem: 456.8MB` 
4. If I repeat step 2 now again, `Real Mem:468.5MB` and `Virtual Mem: 436.5 MB`.

And all the time when I load image, memory consumption is increasing, not getting lower. It gets a little bit lower only if I load much smaller image than the image that is already loaded (app works so that only one image can be loaded at one time).
```

Then I tried to use NSImage to NSBitmapImageRep method. It's almost had no memory leaks, but when using it I met problems with higher DPI images. So how to do it correctly without any memory leaks and as small as possible memory consumption?

Comment: The `NSBitmapImageRep` from `NSImage` is a perfectly fine way to do it. What problems did you have with higher DPI images? You can reduce memory consumption by tiling your image if it's too large for the GPU to process it. Can you describe what you're trying to do with it?

Comment: when image has more DPI than 72 pixels/inch, then image is smaller, because, as I found information over the internet, NSImage makes it smaller so that quality wouldn't be lost. When using CGImage I avoid this problem, but then appears some memory leaks that I can't find.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by "NSImage makes it smaller so that quality wouldn't be lost." If you make it smaller, you're reducing the resolution, and losing quality. Do you have a link to a page which describes the problem?

Comment: If I have image with dimensions 3200x2000 and DPI 300pixels/inch, when you create NSImage from it, you get 768x480 dimensions NSImage. Check it by your self if you don't believe.

Comment: Right - if you want pixel dimensions, you need to get the `NSBitmapImageRep` from it and call `-pixelsHigh` and `-pixelsWide`.

Comment: And when you make NSBitmapImageRep from that NSImage it is the same size as NSImage at least you use `TIFFRepresentation` witch is not always correct and wastes some memory.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are allocating, but not freeing `_bottom_source` and `_gray_out_ciimage` (at least in the code you posted).

Comment: But if I release `_gray_out_ciimage` in the end of method, I get `EXC_BAD_ACCESS` at `[gray_out_filter setValue:_gray_out_ciimage forKey:@"inputImage"];` when running it second time with other image. And if I release `_gray_out_ciimage` at the begining of the method (so that it would be released before setting new value for it), it gives me same error at `CGContextRelease(_bottom_context);`

Comment: Edited question, added more detailed memory leak description.

Comment: Given that, I'd run the Leaks instrument and see if you can determine where the leaks are coming from. It will show you all the allocations, and you can see the stack trace for where they're getting allocated, which should show you the exact line that's leaking. [Here's a tutorial on using Leaks](http://www.raywenderlich.com/2696/how-to-debug-memory-leaks-with-xcode-and-instruments-tutorial).